# best way to interact with objects in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, interaction

I am a beginner in Unity and not really familiar with lots of things and currently making a game for our project. I searched a lot on how to interact with objects but they all have different way to do it so I can't understand what is the best way to implement interactions in the scene.

What I want to do is like when my character come to a table with a newspaper in it, there will be bubble pop up to that says "view" or "read" then 2D assets will pop-up to read the content of the newspaper. What is the best way or maybe the easiest way to do these events?

The game I am creating is a 3d Isometric Perspective game if this helps.

Comment: I would probably go for either continuous distance checks (each interactable checks `if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= SOME_THRESHOLD) { Show(); }`) or you could also simply put a trigger collider on your player and use phyiscs (OnTriggerEnter/Exit) ... either way **"best"** is usually opinion based and depends on the use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add GameObject around the table.

- Add box collider to the GameObject.
- set false to isTrigger option.
- This Collision can handle event when the character comes to around the table.

2. Create Script and add to the GameObject.

> ```
> GameObject popup;
>
> private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
> {
>   if(other.tag == "character") {
>       popup.SetActive(true);
>   }
> }
>
> void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
> {
>   if(other.tag == "character") {
>       popup.SetActive(false);
>   }
> }
> ```